# QT read json keyvalue pairs in a array

Tags: json, qt

Following JSON should be read in a qt, and stored in an array as key value pairs, so I can work with these values:

json:

```
    {
   "datasources":[
   {"id":1,"name":"TPS Position"},
   {"id":2,"name":"TPS Timer"},
   {"id":3,"name":"Lateral G"},
   {"id":4,"name":"Longitudal G"},
   {"id":5,"name":"Z"},
   {"id":6,"name":"AFR"}
]}
```

I read the QT JSON savegame example, but I can't figure out how to read Key values.
This is the qt code that I have, but I don't know how to go on:

```
    jsonFileValue = datasourcesjson.readAll();
    datasourcesjson.close();

    QJsonDocument m_DataSourceDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonFileValue.toUtf8());

    QJsonObject m_DataSourceObject = m_DataSourceDocument.object();

    QJsonArray m_DataSourceArray = m_DataSourceObject.value(QString("datasources")).toArray();
    qWarning() << m_DataSourceArray;
```

This is the output:

```
QJsonArray([{"id":1,"name":"TPS Position"},{"id":2,"name":"TPS Timer"},{"id":3,"name":"Lateral G"},{"id":4,"name":"Longitudal G"},{"id":5,"name":"Z"},{"id":6,"name":"AFR"}])
```

But how can I get this data in an array to work with in my programm like QMap for key values?

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#keys)! - it's really not that hard guys...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can loop through the QJsonArray and get QJsonObject from each member. Then you can get the value by its key. QJsonObject::value() returns QJsonValue type object which can be casted in your case to QString or int.

```
    QJsonDocument m_DataSourceDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonFileValue.toUtf8());

    QJsonObject m_DataSourceObject = m_DataSourceDocument.object();

    QJsonArray m_DataSourceArray = m_DataSourceObject.value(QString("datasources")).toArray();
    qWarning() << m_DataSourceArray;

    for (const auto m_DataSource : m_DataSourceArray)
    // or instead of c++11 for-loop, you can use foreach, like:
    // foreach (const QJsonValue& m_DataSource, m_DataSourceArray)
    {
        QJsonObject m_DataSourceObject = m_DataSource.toObject();
        qWarning() << "Id: "
                 << m_DataSourceObject.value("id").toInt()
                 << " and name: "
                 << m_DataSourceObject.value("name").toString();
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Id:  1  and name:  "TPS Position"
Id:  2  and name:  "TPS Timer"
Id:  3  and name:  "Lateral G"
Id:  4  and name:  "Longitudal G"
Id:  5  and name:  "Z"
Id:  6  and name:  "AFR"
```

If you don't want to loop through all members, you can also read a single value from array.

Following code prints 'name' value of the second member:

```
    qWarning() << m_DataSourceArray.at(1).toObject().value("name").toString();
```

Outputs:

```
"TPS Timer"
```

Hope this helps.